# C++ Overriding logical fail

Tags: c++, oop

Hey guys I have a problem with one of my methods (overriding an operator , ~ ) 
When I try to print my object, something unexpected happens... need some help

this is my whole code

```
#include"stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class complex
{
private:
    double Re, Im; 
public:    
    complex(double _Re = 0, double _Im = 0) : Re(_Re), Im(_Im){} //class constructor  

    void print() const
    {
        cout << Re << " + " << "i(" << Im << ")" << endl;
    }
    complex operator~() const
    {
        return (Re, -Im);
    }
}; 

void main()
{
    complex x(2, 3);
    x.print();
    (~x).print();
}
```

If i compile it, I'll get the correct complex number on the screen, but when I try to execute the ~ overridden operator it displays to me -  `-3 + 0 i`....
Really need some help.
Thanks

Sorry for posting such brain-dead questions, but I can't figure it out by myself....been looking at the damn code for more than 30 minutes and I can't see where I am wrong.

Comment: return(re , -im) --> return complex (re , -im)....sometimes 20 min and 2 eyes are not enough to notice a missing word!

Comment: Don't use identifiers beginning with underscore then a capital letter, like `_Re` and `_Im`.  These are reserved for the C++ library and other implementation details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `complex(Re, -Im);`
in:

```
complex operator~() const
{
    return (Re, -Im);
}
```

Hence you return an implicit converted `complex(-Im)` (comma operator).
You might use explicit constructors to avoid a pitfall like this.

Comment: What this line actually does is use the comma operator.

Answer (score 0):

The comma in

```
return (Re, -Im);
```

does NOT do what you think it does.

Surrounding something in parenthesis does NOT call a constructor.
The parenthesis are discarded and the expression is evaluated as

```
return Re, -Im;
```

The comma means rvaluation each term and the result is the rightmost term.
Because the expression `Re` doesn't do anything the expression is evaluated as

```
return -Im;
```

But this calls the constructor which has a default of 0 for the imaginary term.
And so you get -3 for the real part and 0 for the imaginatry part.

Instead that line should read

```
return complex(Re, -Im);
```

Which constructs what you thought it should.

Answer (score 0):

```
    return (Re, -Im);
```

This is using the comma operator, where it evaluates `Re` (numbers do nothing), and then evaluates and "returns" `-Im` (-3).  Then, the return type is expected to be a `complex`, so it tries to convert this -3 to a `complex`.  It finds this constructor: `complex(double _Re = 0, double _Im = 0)`, and uses it: `complex(-3, 0)`;

The immediate solution is to add the word `complex` to the return

```
    return complex(Re, -Im);
```

Or, in C++11, use `{}` to tell the compiler that you meant to call the constructor:

```
    return {Re, -Im};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you accept default values for your constructor (`0`) the compiler takes the expression: `return (Re, -Im);` evaluates `Re` (it is 2) throws away and creates a new `complex` with the `-Im` by calling the constructor like: `complex(-3, 0)`. So this is how you get the funny value.